# How do you add a placeholder to a cell in excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to add a placeholder in my excel spreadsheet so my workers know what values to put in their and if a value is entered then later deleted someone else knows what to put in their.

Ideally I want a solution for excel online but I can adapt to doing one offline.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a simple macro in the Change event of the Worksheet

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each lCell In Target.Cells
        If lCell.Value = Empty Then
            lCell.Value = "PlaceHolder"
        End If
    Next lCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use excel names. See Formulas tab/Name Manager.